# How to generate and validate a random (and temporary) password in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I need to implement a method to generate a random password and then validate that the user is using the password previously generated.

I really appreciate any help and guidance.
Thank you all!

Comment: Sending passwords to a user in an email is a security risk. Instead consider using 2FA/OTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uniqid()` to generate a random string like this `61595f7b648c0`. then save it on a table drafts linked to users table to check on it again

Comment: Never save clear text passwords! You should hash them before saving them to the database and use a reliable hashing algorithm.

Comment: I didn't say to save them like this !, he was asking for a random generator, i am assuming he knows how to hash !